# Regarding the use of xargs in find command

Tags: linux, find, xargs, tcsh

I have one scenario where I need to select all files having aliencoders.numeric-digits
like alienoders.1206
and find command should search all subdirectories too. If there is no such file it should not do anything.

I wrote :

```
find /home/jassi/ -name "aliencoders.[0-9]+" | xargs ls -lrt | awk print '$9'
```

Bit it says no such file or directory if there no such file starts with aliencoders.xx...

How I can by pass this error. I have to run it for several such directories and it should give output for those directories only in which such file pattern exists else no warning and doesn't do xargs etc stuffs.

Currently, if no such file is there then it is taking current directory t find instead of /home/jassi

Comment: which shell are you using? bash? tcsh?

Comment: also .. you want `awk '{print $9}'` no?

Comment: i m using tcsh and i needed to get all such files in sorted order so xargs ls -lRt and then I need to print only last column that is file name with full path so piping with awk

Comment: If all the directories are in /home/jassi and not in deeper levels, you can excahnge `find` by `for i in "/home/jassi/aliencoders.[0-9]+" ; do ls -lrt $i | awk '{print $9} ; done`.

Comment: No it has some deeper level too and I think either i have to use find command with xargs or File::Find module with regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want `xargs` to execute if the input is empty you can use `-r` or `--no-run-if-empty` which are GNU extensions as pointed out in the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) page. So if you have that support, you can try
`find /home/jassi/ -name "aliencoders.[0-9]+" | xargs -r ls -lrt | awk '{print $9}'`
Alternatively you can make use of `exec` option with `find` to achieve this something on these lines
`find /home/jassi/ -name "aliencoders.[0-9]+" -exec ls -lrt {} + | awk '{print $9}'`
Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually,
find /home/jassi/ -name "aliencoders.[0-9]+" command was fetching everything from the current directory too.
So I changed it to  find /home/jassi/ -type f -name "aliencoders.[0-9]+" then it's working fine else it was giving unusual result.

and -r option in xargs doesn't seem to be working. I am in tcsh shell.

I will update again.

Answer (score 1):

**bash**:

Try this command (under the `bash` shell since most people use it, and no shell was specified):

```
find /home/jassi/ -name "aliencoders.[0-9]+" 2>&1 | xargs ls -lrt | awk '{print $9}'
```

With `2>&1` you are redirecting the error messages from `stderr` to `stdout`. Once you have this single output stream, you can process it with your pipes etc.

Without this redirection, your error messages to `stderr` would have continued to go to the console, creating clutter in the output and only `stdout` was getting processed by the pipes.

[All about redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) will give you more details and control about redirection.

**UPDATE**:

**tcsh**:

Based on use of the `tcsh` (sometimes I think I'm the only one using it), it is possible to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` with the following construct:

```
command |& ...
```

so

```
find /home/jassi/ -name "aliencoders.[0-9]+" |& xargs ls -lrt | awk '{print $9}'
```

should help. Before your error messages were bypassing your pipes and going directly to the console, only `stdout` was getting processed by your pipes. With this **all** of your output goes through the pipes and you can filter out what you want.

Also, note the use of the `awk` command at the end of the command:

```
awk '{print $9}'
```

is different from what you posted originally.

Comment: Thanks guys. It actually solved the issue. I used -r with xargs which seems little more efficient than exec command

and just added type -f in find command too. It worked the way we were thinking.

Thanks again